# Downloading subset of MODIS data through HTTPS

Tags: python, modis

I need to download 'MYD04_3K - MODIS/Aqua Aerosol 5-Min L2 Swath 3km' data for India. I found two ways to download it:

1. Go to [the website](https://ladsweb.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/archive/allData/) and select product details etc. I have been able to automate this process using Python. But, one of the drawbacks is that there is no way to subset the data. There are no **location specific ids** (e.g. tile code etc.) in the file names. So, one will have to download the files for the entire world, process the data, and then subset the data.
2. Go to [the website](https://ladsweb.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/archive/allData/) and select product details etc. Select the product, time, location and process the order. Here, I am basically ordering the files using website's web-service. It does not allow you to download more than files 2000 files at a time. The links/details are then sent to my email and I can use the links to download the data.

Is there any way I can use an API or write a script to download data for a particular location without availing website's order/processing feature? I want to automate the download rather than going to website and order the data every time I download.

Edit: This question is not a duplicate of the [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/206774/modisdownload-error-downloading-only-portion-of-hdf-files) suggested. As I mentioned in the original question, I want to avoid subsetting the files manually on the website, and also, I have not found any location specific details in the filename. Here is a sample filename: MYD04_3K.A2004001.0015.061.2018012003848.hdf

Some datasets from MODIS have tile information, which can be used to download only subset of the data. In my case, I couldn't find any such thing. So, I asked if anyone knows how to download the subset of data automatically, without manual selection.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ModisDownload error downloading only portion of hdf files](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/206774/modisdownload-error-downloading-only-portion-of-hdf-files)

Comment: This looks like a duplicate. Please see - https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/206774/modisdownload-error-downloading-only-portion-of-hdf-files/207157#207157

Comment: I have added the explanation. It does not seem to be duplicate. In case I missed anything, let me know.

Comment: Do you really need swath data? Usually researchers use Level 3 tiled products for regional studies. They are easier to locate and use. With swath data indeed you would have to do orbital calculations to figure out which granule has the data you need. I am genuinely interested as we were developing a tool for swath data indexing at current_job-1.

Comment: This is more of an Open Data question than a GIS question.